# How to put default value in arrays?

Tags: arrays, yii2

How can I put default 0 in array?

```
<?= (!in_array($f['id'], Yii::$app->session[Yii::$app->params['cart-session']])) ? ' add-to- 
    cart' : '' ?>
```

Comment: Which array do you want to initialize with 0? What is the actual response that you want to achieve? Please share more info.

Comment: in in_array($f['id'] if not value are there in $f array

Comment: check out https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-merge.php for merging values

Comment: check out null coalescing operator ??:
Yii::$app->session[Yii::$app->params['cart-session']] ?? 0

Answer (score 0):

```
$f = array(0);
```

More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp